# Is the $C^0$-fine topology finer than the metric topology?

Tags: differential-topology

Let $C(E,F)$ be the set of continouos maps between metric spaces $E$ and $F$. Suppose we are given the $C^0$ fine topology and a metric topology on $C(E,F)$. We know that the fine topology is finer than the compact-open topology, but is it finer than metric topology?

Comment: How is there a metric topology on $C(E,F)$? Is $E$ compact?